# Three points to normal notation (interpret the math)

Tags: 3d, mathematics, vector

From: [Euclidian Space: Planes](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/elements/plane/index.htm), I see the formula:

> **Convert Three points to normal notation**
>
> N = (p1-p0) × (p2 - p0)
>
> d = -N • p0^2
>
> where:
>
> N = normal to plane (not necessarily unit length) d = perpendicular
>   distance of plane from origin. p0,p1 and p2 = vertex points x = cross
>   product

When calculating the distance to the origin from the plane (d)...
A) how is the p0 squared?
B) how do I resolve the dot product of the vector (-N dot p0^2) to scalar distance?

Comment: This may be a better question for the math exchange, but I think the page you've referenced is being a bit sloppy or misleading with its description. The formula given for `d` does not correspond to Euclidean distance from the origin. (To demonstrate, replace `p1` with a new point `p3` which is twice as far from `p0` while remaining on the same plane. We've now doubled the length of `N` and quadrupled the value of `d`, even though we didn't move the plane at all!). Instead I'd expect an expression like `d = dot(N, p0)/length(N)`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @DMGregory, I think I have it.

```
n = (p1 - p0).cross(p2 - p0);
n = normalize(n);
d = n.dot(p0);
```

Where p0, p1 and p2 are points. n is the (unit) normal vector and d is the distance to the origin from the plane.